# reinsert capture group in replace beside a number

Tags: regex, powershell

Here is an example. Trying to reinsert the captured subdomain, but it is causing a problem since the parent domain begins with a number.

```
'127.0.0.1 test.2domain.com' -replace '127.0.0.1 (.*)2domain.com', '192.168.1.1 $12domain.com'
```

If you put a space the regex variable expands properly, but it's also inserting the space.

```
'127.0.0.1 test.2domain.com' -replace '127.0.0.1 (.*)2domain.com', '192.168.1.1 $1 2domain.com'
```

I know I can just do another replace at this point to get rid of it, I'd like to know though if there is a way to accomplish the first example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can put the `-replace` code inside a [subexpression `$(...)`](http://ss64.com/ps/syntax-operators.html):

```
PS > "$('127.0.0.1 test.2domain.com' -replace '127.0.0.1 (.*)2domain.com', '192.168.1.1 $1')2domain.com"
192.168.1.1 test.2domain.com
PS >
```

Notice too that I used quotation marks `"..."` to enclose the string.  You need these so that the subexpression is evaluated.

Answer (score 2):

As an alternative, you could wrap the rest of the regex in a group of it's own, like:

```
PS > '127.0.0.1 test.2domain.com' -replace '127.0.0.1 (.*)(2domain.com)', '192.168.1.1 $1$2'
192.168.1.1 test.2domain.com
```